# Bosch BNO055 gyroscope bias stability

Tags: integrated-circuit, accelerometer, imu, gyroscope, magnetometer

What is the bias stability in degrees/hour of the gyroscope on the BNO055? The  [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST_BNO055_DS000_12.pdf) lists some specs of the gyro on page #14 but I cant find the bias there. There is an item called "output noise" that lists 0.1 degrees/s - is this the bias? I actually am looking for following two values (sample taken from Xsens MTi 1-series):

- Gyroscope bias stability: 10 deg/hr
- Gyroscope noise density: 0.01º/s/√Hz

Comment: No, that corresponds to the noise density (they quote a bandwidth of 47Hz and helpfully convert it to º/s/√Hz for you.

Comment: The bias is typically +/- 1 degree/sec, worst case +/-3 degrees/sec on page 14.  (not useful as a north seeker).

Comment: Ok, so they call it "Zero-rate Offset" - I am looking for a higher quality gyro with say bias up to 20 degrees/hour. So this Bosch will give typically 1*3600 = 3600 degrees/hour.

Comment: Yes.  When still, this gyro will report that it is slowly turning by this amount.  The type of gyro you want is going to be a navigational grade and pretty expensive.  Typically they have a caged spinning mass, sometimes powered by a hysteresis motor.  I haven't heard of any solid state gyros that approach this accuracy.

Comment: The Xsens gyros and Analog Devices iSensor gyros are both MEMS and can do around 10 deg/hour at best. Both priced in $100s or lower $1000s (depending on accuracy). The entry level units do around 20 deg/h for about $200-300 which I think is very good value still.

Comment: @Kozuch I guess I stand corrected!  I can't see how a bare mems gyro can approach this level of bias.  Do you know what the term "in-run" bias stability means?  Is there specmanship going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there are any solid state gyros with this type of bias.  I think you will need an electromechanical device.  Consider that while sitting on the equator, a perfect gyro will report 15 degrees per hour from the earth spinning on its axis, so you are trying to sense rotation of this small magnitude.  Such gyros so exist but may cost thousands of dollars depending on the size (larger gyros are easier to build at this sensitivity.)  They are generally used in military aircraft, weapons or navigational applications.

Comment: Ring laser gyros and ring fiber gyros (these are more common and better than laser variant) far out perform the mechanical versions and are the only gyros designed into these types of systems in the last 15 years or so.

Comment: MEMS is electromechanical, isnt it? So you think that [this](https://www.xsens.com/download/pdf/documentation/mti-1/mti-1-series_product_summary.pdf) and [this](http://www.analog.com/media/en/news-marketing-collateral/solutions-bulletins-brochures/MEMS-IMU-Brochure.pdf) datasheets lie? I think they may count the "extra" degrees besides earth rotation (so 20 may mean 15+20=35 in total) - I dont know how the specs are created.

Comment: @placeholder, electromechanical gyros are still in use when operation at small size and high temperature is required.  You are right though, not too many are left.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough rep to comment, but wanted to correct a comment by @John Birckhead.  The bias instability is the minimum on the Allan Variance curve, which represents low-frequency noise (similar to drift) that cannot be corrected by averaging more samples (see [article](https://www.novatel.com/assets/Documents/Bulletins/APN064.pdf)).  It is how stable the bias is during a run.  The "initial bias" refers to the change in bias from run to run (after turning off the device) and  I believe that is what Bosch refers to as the zero-rate offset.  It's confusing as both parameters are reported in the native units of deg/s.

> **Bias Repeatability** (Turn-on to Turn-on Bias): 
>   For each powerup of the IMU, the initial bias is different. This is due to a number of effects,including change in the physical properties of the IMU and initial conditions of signal processing. A very repeatable bias allows for better "tuning" of IMU parameters by the INS to quickly reach a good estimate of the bias. A high variability in the turn-on to turn-on bias, leads to a longer and more difficult estimation period (convergence) for every start up.

---

> **Bias Stability** (In-run Bias):
>   While the IMU is powered on, the initial bias changes over time. This change in bias is often related to temperature, time and/or mechanical stress on the system. In the case of light based gyroscopes (Fibre Optic Gyro (FOG)/Ring Laser 
>    yro (RLG)), the optical length increases or decreases with the change in the physical properties of the IMU. Often, IMUs are manufactured with temperature compensation, increasing the stability of the measurements. An INS filter constantly estimates the bias by making use of external sources of information
>   (GNSS, DMI, barometer). The estimated bias value is removed from the IMU measurements before using them in the mechanization. The process of estimating the bias is more effective when stable. The effect of bias stability
>   can be observed directly in the outage performance.